# Linq Query For matching at least Five Numbers From the Given List

Tags: c#, linq

i have a list - `finalbetfile2`

The class is,

```
 class finalbetfile
    {
        public int[] BetInfo{ get; set; }
        public string TransID { get; set; }
        public string BetAmount { get; set; }
        public string TransDateTime { get; set; }

    }
```

The `BetInfo` column has six integers values,
I want to match the `Betinfo` with my `rank3of1`(Result) with any order,the code is given below

```
 var rank3of1 = new int[] { intball1, intball2, intball3, intball4, intball5, intball6 };
 var filteredProjects8 = finalbetfile2.Where(p => rank3of1.All(tag => p.BetInfo.Contains(tag)));
```

It works fine but matching against all 6 numbers instead of at least 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of `All` and check if this count is greater than or equal to 5

```
finalbetfile2.Where(p => rank3of1.Count(tag => p.BetInfo.Contains(tag)) >= 5);
```

Comment: For the record, I think `Intersect` is far more efficient.

Comment: @GertArnold - It may be, but intersect wouldn't be the part of the code that solves the issue, you still need the count

Comment: Of course. It's about Intersect vs `n` times Contains.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var filteredProjects8 = finalbetfile2
    .Where(p => rank3of1.Intersect(p.BetInfo).Count() >= 5);
```